# Creating a nasty loop to get an Array of Objects within another Array of Objects inside JSON file

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, loops, ecmascript-6

I'm having a very difficult time reading a very large JSON file. I attached the screenshot of the portion I'm having trouble with. The problem is, I'm able to map over one set of an Array of Objects, however, when I try to access another array of objects within this loop, it returns [object],[object] for all of the items. I can stringify this, but that does not help, it just returns a whole bunch of code I can't use. I feel like I should be calling on the inner loop or looping within another loop, but I have not been successful. Would anyone please help me with this one? It is taking me a very long time, and I just want to understand and learn how to solve this! I want the objects to read their actual value, not just object.

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    console.log( "ready!" );

$.ajax({
    url: "hidden",
    type: "get",
    async: true,
    contentType: "application/jsonp",
    dataType: "jsonp",
    success: function(data) {
        console.log(data.programs.program.requirements);

        $('.wrapper').append('<div class="overview"> ' + data.programs.program.requirements[2].title + ' </div>');
        // return content, which is an array of object, so to get items I need to use a loop
        var credits = data.programs.program.requirements[2].requirement_list.map(function(item) {
            $('.wrapper').append('<div class="overview"> ' + item.title +  item.course +' </div>');
        })
    }
});
});
```

[screenshot of JSON file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L4Us0.jpg)

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, a *specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: It is clear. Thanks.

Comment: No, it's not. Please add more context - what **exactly** is the problem? A JSON object never "returns a whole bunch of code"

Comment: What do you mean by "another array of objects"? Is it another request, pagination maybe? Are you sure that this another call contains proper json data? Maybe data returned by server is actually "[object][object]"? Check in console what is actually returned by this request.